# Is it possible to have related field in both ways?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-12

I don't know if the title is properly correct.

I have a model called **"*web.support.ticket*"**, it has a One2many field connected with "*account.analytic.line*" through **analytic_timesheet_ids** field.

Then, I have another model called **"*web.support.ticket.compose*"** this model is a wizard form, and it sends an email to some contacts. This model has a Many2one field connected with **"*web.support.ticket*"** through **ticket_id** field also.

**"*web.support.ticket.compose*"** also has a One2many field connected with **"*account.analytic.line*"** through **analytic_timesheet_ids** field.

My idea is that, whenever I edit some field in **"*account.analytic.line*"** from **"*web.support.ticket*"**, this edits (or creation) will appear on **"*account.analytic.line*"** from **"*web.support.ticket.compose*"** AND VICE VERSA

I've tried using related fields, but the problem with that is that I cannot edit the *related* field.

Also, I've tried this:

```
def create(self, vals):
    res = super(AccountAnalyticLine, self).create(vals)
    if compose_id:
        vals['ticket_id'] = compose_id
```

Comment: I strongly suspect your question as written is too broad to be properly answered.   Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit your related field if you set the readonly attribute to False:

```
analytic_timesheet_ids = fields.One2many(
        comodel_name='account.analytic.line',
        related='ticket_id.analytic_timesheet_ids',
        readonly=False
    )
```